# Scraping track data from HTML?

Tags: ruby, xpath, sinatra, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'd like to be able to scrape data from a track list page at 1001tracklists. A URL example is:

```
http://www.1001tracklists.com/tracklist/25122_lange-intercity-podcast-115-2013-03-06.html
```

Here is an example of how the data is displayed on the page:

```
Above & Beyond - Black Room Boy (Above & Beyond Club Mix) [ANJUNABEATS]
```

I'd like to pull out all the songs from this page in the following format:

```
$byArtist - $name [$publisher]
```

After reviewing the HTML for this page, it appears the content I am after is stored in HTML5 meta microdata format:

```
<td class="" id="tlptr_433662">
<a name="tlp_433662"></a>
<div itemprop="tracks" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicRecording" id="tlp5_content">
<meta itemprop="byArtist" content="Above &amp; Beyond">
<meta itemprop="name" content="Black Room Boy (Above &amp; Beyond Club Mix)">
<meta itemprop="publisher" content="ANJUNABEATS">
<meta itemprop="url" content="/track/103905_above-beyond-black-room-boy-above-beyond-club-mix/index.html">
<span class="tracklistTrack floatL"id="tr_103905" ><a href="/track/103905_above-beyond-black-room-boy-above-beyond-club-mix/index.html" class="">Above &amp; Beyond - Black Room Boy (Above &amp; Beyond Club Mix)</a>&thinsp;</span><span class="floatL">[<a href="/label/1037_anjunabeats/index.html" title="Anjunabeats">ANJUNABEATS</a>]</span>  
<div id="tlp5_actions" class="floatL" style="margin-top:1px;">
```

There is a CSS selector with a "tlp_433662" value. Each song on the page will have its own unique id. One will have "tlp_433662" and the next will have "tlp_433628" or something similar.

Is there a way to extract all songs listed on the tracklist page using Nokogiri and XPath?
I will probably want to "do" an "each" on my "data" listed below so that the **scraper** loops over the data extracting each set of relevant data. Here is the start of my Ruby program:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.1001tracklists.com/tracklist/25122_lange-intercity-podcast-115-2013-03-06.html"
data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
# what do do next? print out xpath loop code which extracts my data.
# code block I need help with
data.xpath.........each do |block|
block.xpath("...........").each do |span|
    puts stuff printing out what I want.
end
end
```

My ultimate goal, which I know how to do, is to take this Ruby script to Sinatra to "webify" the data and add some nice Twitter bootstrap CSS as shown in this youtube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWI1PIvy4A8

Can you help me with the XPath code block so that I can scrape the data and print the array?

Comment: Try `//div[@itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicRecording"]`

Comment: You should at least _try_ to do it yourself before asking for help.

Comment: I have tried and that is why I am asking. The xpath portion is new to me and I've read documentation but am still having trouble. I've searched and wouldn't have asked this question had I not given it several attempts to learn.

Comment: First you would have to use `//div[@itemprop="tracks"]` to find all track nodes, then iterate thru them and use `//meta[@itemprop="byArtist"]/@content` (as example to get artist's name) to get your values

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'rest-client'

url = 'http://www.1001tracklists.com/tracklist/25122_lange-intercity-podcast-115-2013-03-06.html'
page = Nokogiri::HTML(RestClient.get(url,:user_agent=>'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'), nil, 'UTF-8');

page.css('table.detail tr.tlpItem').each do |row|
  artist = row.css('meta[@itemprop="byArtist"]').attr('content')
  name = row.css('meta[@itemprop="name"]').attr('content')

  puts "#{artist} - #{name}"
end
```

...a more advanced version, that grabs all the meta info from the row and prints 'Artist - Song [Publisher]

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'rest-client'

url = 'http://www.1001tracklists.com/tracklist/25122_lange-intercity-podcast-115-2013-03-06.html'
page = Nokogiri::HTML(RestClient.get(url,:user_agent=>'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'), nil, 'UTF-8');

page.css('table.detail tr.tlpItem').each do |row|

  meta  = row.search('meta').each_with_object({}) do |tag, hash|
    hash[tag['itemprop']] = tag['content']
  end

  puts "#{meta['byArtist']} - #{meta['name']} [#{meta['publisher']||'Unknown'}]"
end
```

You get the picture for the rest of the properties. You will need to do some error/exists? checking because some songs don't have all the properties. But this should get you on the right track. I've also used the `rest-client` gem so feel free to use whatever you want to retrieve the page.

Comment: Whoops, I left the code in by accident. Wrote this at work and I have cntlm running on my machine which is an NTLM auth proxy. That's not needed obviously if you're running in a proxy free environment.

Comment: Strelok,Thank you so much for the help. I am moving along with scraping this data. You made my day. I removed the proxy line as it is not needed in my environment. My next step is to figure out an if else statement to check if the "publisher" value is nil. Any guidance here? I'd like to check if the publisher value exists and if it doesn't do the following: puts "#{artist} - #{name}" [#{recordlabel}]" or puts "#{artist} - #{name}" [Unknown]" Also no track is found showing ID - ID the code throws an exception: `attr': undefined method `attribute' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code to gather the information into an array of hashes.

I prefer using CSS accessors over XPath, because they're more readable if you have any HTML/CSS or jQuery experience.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.1001tracklists.com/tracklist/25122_lange-intercity-podcast-115-2013-03-06.html'))
data = doc.search('tr.tlpItem div[itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicRecording"]').each_with_object([]) do |div, array|
  hash = div.search('meta').each_with_object({}) do |m, h|
    h[m['itemprop']] = m['content']
  end

  link = div.at('span a')
  hash['tracklistTrack'] = [ link['href'], link.text ]

  title = div.at('span.floatL a')
  hash['title'] = [title['href'], title.text ]

  array << hash
end

pp data[0, 2]
```

Which outputs a subset of the page's data. After some massaging the structure looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "byArtist"=>"Markus Schulz",
    "name"=>"The Spiritual Gateway (Transmission 2013 Theme)",
    "publisher"=>"COLDHARBOUR RECORDINGS",
    "url"=>"/track/108928_markus-schulz-the-spiritual-gateway-transmission-2013-theme/index.html",
    "tracklistTrack"=>[
        "/track/108928_markus-schulz-the-spiritual-gateway-transmission-2013-theme/index.html",
        "Markus Schulz - The Spiritual Gateway (Transmission 2013 Theme)"
      ],
    "title"=>[
      "/track/108928_markus-schulz-the-spiritual-gateway-transmission-2013-theme/index.html",
      "Markus Schulz - The Spiritual Gateway (Transmission 2013 Theme)"
    ]
  },
  {
    "byArtist"=>"Lange & Audrey Gallagher",
    "name"=>"Our Way Home (Noah Neiman Remix)",
    "publisher"=>"LANGE RECORDINGS",
    "url"=>"/track/119667_lange-audrey-gallagher-our-way-home-noah-neiman-remix/index.html",
    "tracklistTrack"=>[
      "/track/119667_lange-audrey-gallagher-our-way-home-noah-neiman-remix/index.html",
      "Lange & Audrey Gallagher - Our Way Home (Noah Neiman Remix)"
    ],
    "title"=>[
      "/track/119667_lange-audrey-gallagher-our-way-home-noah-neiman-remix/index.html",
      "Lange & Audrey Gallagher - Our Way Home (Noah Neiman Remix)"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is this free webservice wich **scrapes** all the 400+ schema.org classes from given url and give them back as JSON

http://scrappy.netfluid.org/